# Initializing reference member variable with literal

Tags: c++, variables, reference, initialization

In the following code , I am initializing a reference variable with a literal.

```
class ABC
{
  public:
     const int& a;
     ABC():a(43) { }
     void newfoo()
     {
           printf("NEWFOO %d",a);
     }
};
int main()
{
   ABC obj;
   obj.newfoo();
}
```

The output of this program is `NEWFOO 32767` which seems illogical when I know that the following code works just fine.

```
int main()
{ 
  const int& b=3;
  printf("%d",b);
}
```

What is happening here ? If compiler declares some temp variable during initializing of the reference variable , then isn't the scope of that variable will be inside main since the class is in global scope ?

Comment: Don't initialize member references with literals. I believe it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Why was it standardized this way? It doesn't make sense to let this compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `clang` produces the following warning for this code even without any flags (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6902abb44681f88b)*):

```
warning: binding reference member 'a' to a temporary value [-Wdangling-field]
 ABC():a(43) { }
         ^~
```

`gcc` on the other hand requires either `-Wall` or `-Wextra`.

and if we check out [this reference initialization reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization) it says:

> a temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor initializer list persists only until the constructor exits, not as long as the object exists.

This can be found in the draft C++ standard section `12.2` *Temporary objects* paragraph *5* which includes the following bullet

> — A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits.

Answer (score 2):

A temporary will be created and the reference is bound to that temporary (C++03 8.5.3.5).  The temporary will be destroyed at the end of the constructor call, leaving a dangling reference.  This is specified in C++03 12.2.5:

> A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor's ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits.