# Why do clang and g++ print 0 for a1.v and a2.v in this example in C++1z?

Tags: c++, c++17

See this example in [[class.base.init]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.init#class.base.init-11)

```
struct A {
  A() = default;          // OK
  A(int v) : v(v) { }     // OK
  const int& v = 42;      // OK
};
A a1;                     // error: ill-formed binding of temporary to reference
A a2(1);                  // OK, unfortunately
```

Both clang and g++ compile the code (clang with a warning), but I'd like to understand why do they print `0` for the members `a1.v` and `a2.v`? See [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1df5b497e582732e).

Comment: Strictly related (almost dup): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481481/initializing-reference-member-variable-with-literal

Answer (score 12):

It doesn't matter that they print `0`.

For `a1`, the initialization is ill-formed to begin with. For `a2`, you're binding a reference to a temporary so you end up with a dangling reference. There's no significance to the `0` - it's whatever garbage memory the reference happens to point to at that point. Once you're violating preconditions, the program is undefined behavior.

Undefined behavior is undefined. There's no reason to expect a particular behavior for the print. For instance, gcc 7 prints 32764 while clang 4 prints 32765. Why? Why not.

Comment: @Barry I think, you should be more precise about undefined and ill-formed behavior. As we are talking about new standards, both a1 and a2 are clearly ill-formed, check DR 1696.

Comment: @Barry [class.temporary]/5 (5.1) used to be: `A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits`, in C++14. But this bullet point doesn't exist anymore in [\[class.temporary\]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6).

Comment: @overseas I don't understand your comment. `a1` is ill-formed, as I said, `a2` is not ill-formed. This question uses the example from that defect report, which itself indicates that `a2` is not ill-formed.

Comment: @Barry I finally agree with what you said. But there is one additional point I'd like to understand: the initialization of `a1` and `a2`, why is it ill-formed for `a1` and well-formed for `a2`?

Comment: @JoãoAfonso You cited in your question why it's ill-formed for `a1`. There is simply nothing ill-formed about `a2` - you're binding a reference to an lvalue. That's allowed.